# After adding icon to home screen, the icon in the apps screen remains

Tags: applications

I have put a few applications in a folder on the home screen, but their icons are still displayed on one of the apps screens.

How can I remove those still on the apps screen?

Answer (score 1):

The app icon on the home screen is just a shortcut to the app. The purpose of the app drawer is to show *all* installed apps.

If an app is installed, you can't remove it from the app drawer, unless you uninstall the app itself.

Consider the icons placed on your home screen as shortcuts, like on desktop in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot remove an app from the apps screen ! 
when u add the icon of a particular app on your home screen , you are just creating a quick shortcut to that particular app.
But if you really want to remove an app from your app drawer you could simply hide it with the help of applications from the play store ! .

Answer (score 0):

Look for alternative launcher apps in the play store. See if they have the functionality of hiding or grouping apps in the app drawer.

[Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher.prime&hl=en) has this functionality only in the paid version.